# How to select the members who has the age more than 18 (from current date) by SQL in teradata?

Tags: query, teradata

If we are having a table named 'MEMBERS' with below details,
then how to fetch the data from the table with the age 18 or more?

```
S.no  Name     DOB        City
1     sam     19890203   USA
2     andrew  20020304   UK
3     karun   20050827   sydney
4     virat   19870202   India
5     mrunal  19920802   India
```

Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: What's the datatype of DOB, DATE or INT?

Answer (score 1):

Simple logic is based on comparing DOB with the date 18 years before today.

If the datatype of DOB is DATE:

```
where DOB < add_months(current_date, -18*12)
```

If it's an INT:

```
where DOB < cast(add_months(current_date, -18*12) as int) + 19000000
```

If you want to show the age

```
trunc(months_between(current_date, DOB)/12)
```

or for INT

```
trunc(months_between(current_date, cast(DOB - 19000000 as date))/12)
```

+/- 19000000 is based on the internal format of a Teradata date:

```
(year - 1900) * 10000
+ month * 100
+ day
```

Comment: ADD_MONTHS subtracts 18 years from today and then this date is converted to an INT with YYYYMMDD format (based on that internal format). E.g. 2020-08-10 -> 2002-08-10 -> (2002-1900)*10000+8*100+10 -> 1020810 +19000000 -> 20200810